# move shape with S:move MXML

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mxml, flash-builder

I'm trying to create an animation with an rectangle.
I want the rectangle to move in a loop from x=150 to x=50 and back to 150 and so on.

At the moment I can only move the rectangle forward and it stops after it moved 100px.

Any ideas how to create the loop ?

This is what I have come up with. not much Iknow.

```
<s:Move id="moves" 
target="{rect2}"
xBy="-150"
duration="1000"
easer="{sineEasing}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
<mx:Sequence id="seq" repeatCount="0">
    <s:Move
        target="{rect}"
        xBy="150"
        duration="1000"
        easer="{sineEasing}"/>
    <s:Move
        target="{rect}"
        xBy="-150"
        duration="1000"
        easer="{sineEasing}"/>
</mx:Sequence>
```

As you can see the main idea here is using `Sequence` effect to force two `Move` animations to execute in a row and then looping this `Sequence` effect by setting its `repeatCount` property to `0`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, had missed the sequence and repeatcount. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [tweenlite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) animation library and not using the built-in animation options of Flex nor MXML for animation. Tweenlite has a lot more options and is very easy to use.

With the below code, you can see how the library works. The function moves your object rect to the position 65,117 with Sine.easeIn easing over a period of 1 second.

```
TweenLite.to(rect, 1, {x:65, y:117, ease:Sine.easeIn});
```

If you then use some additional parameters, you can create a loop, like this:

```
handleAnimation();

private function handleAnimation(e:Event=null):void
{
    var positionTo:Int = (rect.x == 150) ? 50 : 150;
    TweenLite.to(rect, 1, {x:positionTo, ease:Sine.easeIn, onComplete:handleAnimation});
}
```

Comment: I need to try this a little later, the handleAnimation, needs to be written in the AS code ? I'm I right ? haven't figure out yet were to find that code :)

Comment: This is indeed actionscript. Code should be written in between the following mxml: <fx:Script><![CDATA[ YOUR CODE HERE ]]></fx:Script>